# What type of eye protection should you use with a battery tab welder?

Tags: batteries

There are a ton of youtube videos and websites about how to make a DIY battery tab welder - however none of them seem to have any information on what type of eye protection to use.

I know that some people making small tac welds with regular welders will line things up and then just look away or close their eyes while pulling the trigger - is that what's supposed to be done here as well?

I know that the big welding helmets have auto darkening adjustments but it takes a small period of time for the adjustment to happen - perhaps the battery weld would be so quick that it would not be worth using a helmet for this?

Below is an excerpt from [Jim's Blog](http://jimlaurwilliams.org/wordpress/?p=2418) showing one of the upgrades he made to his version of the welder. It also shows him using the welder but he does not appear to be using any helmet or goggles.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: If you are doing this with lithium ion batteries you'd be wise to take more safety precautions than just covering your eyes in case they explode.

Comment: If this it's off topic, so is any question on soldering, ffs.

Comment: @LeonHeller - I looked for a "welding" stack exchange but did not see one. Thought the community here would have some insight into this question as it deals with building things after they have been engineered, and using things that have been engineered and built ( capacitance discharge resistance welders ) - but yes I can see your point about it being off-topic

Comment: @cwd - Eye injuries from welding are not fun.  I have had patients who were in a hurry and doing just a 'small" amount of welding so they didn't wear darkened glasses and suffered burns from welding.  The worst problem is the corneal burns and abrasions and ulcers which appear from the intensity of the welding light.  Vision can be severely affected and it is extremely painful, but with proper treatment most recover very well.  If there is light created wear glasses that are darkened, if the possibility of projectiles exist then use safety goggles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally capacitance discharge **resistance** welders do not create a visible arc- the heating not from an arc and it is confined to a small region where the parts are in contact.

It is possible to have a small amount of material (i.e. molten metal) ejected from the weld area, particularly if the power level is too high. For this reason, it's recommended to wear safety glasses (an industrial safety procedure would **require** it).

His home-brew setup has the potential to create a visible spark, but it should be brief and not very intense. The poor control over pressure means that the risk of ejecting material is greater.

If it was me, I'd wear ordinary safety goggles.

Comment: Don't forget that although most corneal ulcers and burns are caused by the intensity of the light produced by welding, iritis and similar corneal injuries can occur if significant UV light is produced.  I don't know if this type of welding can produce UV.  Just a thought.